absolute position is not woking with backdrop-filter
Here is the problem: When I remove backdrop-filter, the absolute element is positioned relative to the body, which is what I want. But if I add backdrop-filter, it is positioned relative to root.


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

#root {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  background-color: #46443e96;
  backdrop-filter: blur(19px) saturate(180%);
  /* Problem Here */
}

.left {
  /* display: flex; */
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.item {
  /* flex-shrink: 0; */
  border: 3px solid orange;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
<div id="root">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="absolute">absolute</div>
  </div>
</div>



I don't understand why and I need a solution.

AFAIK you can't without using negative values. Is there any reason why the absolute div have to be under root instead of simply moving it out ?

Right in the spec: "A computed value of other than 'none' results in the creation of both a stacking context ... and a Containing Block for absolute and fixed position descendants, unless the element it applies to is a document root element in the current browsing context."

@SyndRain Just out of curiosity.

@Libra then the reason is as mentioned above. The common solution will be adding a pseudo-element to the root and apply the filter on it instead, or just move the absolute div out. Should exist a StackOverflow post out there for all these but I can't find it now.
